# Fatal Error on WP-Admin Page with Go Market premium theme

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming, cart

I recently bought a **Go Market** ecommerce theme from themeforest. All were good, but suddenly when I go to wp-admin page it shows this error:

> Call to a member function get_cart() on null in /home/amarmart/public_html/wp-content/themes/wp_woo_gomarket/framework/functions/woo-cart.php on line 9

Here is the related **`woo-cart.php`** PHP file code:

```
<?php
if ( ! function_exists( 'wd_tini_cart' ) ) {
    function wd_tini_cart(){
        $_actived = apply_filters( 'active_plugins', get_option( 'active_plugins' )  );
        if ( !in_array( "woocommerce/woocommerce.php", $_actived ) ) {
            return;
        }
        global $woocommerce;
    /*LINE NO- 9*/  $_cart_empty = sizeof( $woocommerce->cart->get_cart() ) > 0 ? false : true ;

        ob_start();

        ?>
        <?php do_action( 'wd_before_tini_cart' ); ?>
        <div class="wd_tini_cart_wrapper">
            <div class="wd_tini_cart_control ">

                <span class="cart_size">
                    <a href="<?php echo $woocommerce->cart->get_cart_url();?>" title="<?php _e('View your shopping bag','wpdance');?>">
                        <span><?php _e('my cart','wpdance');?> </span>
                    </a>
                    : <!--<span class="cart_subtotal"><?php echo $woocommerce->cart->get_cart_subtotal(); ?></span>
                    <span class="cart_division">/</span>-->
                    (<span id="cart_size_value_head"><?php echo $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_count;?></span>)</span>

            </div>
```

I am confused that, what is the connection between cart page and wp-admin login page?

What should be the solution or reason?

Can anyone help me with that issue...

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This code is a little outdated. Actually instead of using for cart:

```
    global $woocommerce;
    /*LINE NO- 9*/  
    $_cart_empty = sizeof( $woocommerce->cart->get_cart() ) > 0 ? false : true;
```

We only use this new syntax *(without `global $woocommerce;` anymore)*:

```
    WC()->cart->get_cart() // …
```

Try to avoid this error, with this dedicated conditional method in WC_Cart class  by replacing that line 9 with:

```
    $_cart_empty = WC()->cart->is_empty(); // which will do the same…
```

> You should contact theme authors opening a support thread, to make them update the code, because this error is not normal.

They should replace **`$woocommerce->cart`** by **`WC()->cart`** everywhere, first.